# The exclusive use of VARIANT in a COM interface

Tags: c++, windows, com, idl

I've inherited a project that includes a COM DLL. I'm sort of new to COM but something doesn't seem right. The interface defined in the IDL only uses the `VARIANT` type for all properties and method returns/parameters. Is there any possible justification for this? I have a feeling the previous developer was just winging some things, but I want to be sure.

Here's what my IDL looks like:

```
interface IMyComInterface : IDispatch
{
    [id(1), helpstring("method CheckMessage")] HRESULT CheckMessage([in] VARIANT vMsg);
    [id(2), helpstring("method CheckFolder")] HRESULT CheckFolder([in] VARIANT Folder, [out] VARIANT *pCount, [out, retval] VARIANT *pErrorCount);
    [propget, id(3), helpstring("property Flags")] HRESULT Flags([out, retval] VARIANT *pVal);
    [propput, id(3), helpstring("property Flags")] HRESULT Flags([in] VARIANT newVal);
    [propget, id(4), helpstring("property MessageStore")] HRESULT MessageStore([out, retval] VARIANT *pVal);
    [propput, id(4), helpstring("property MessageStore")] HRESULT MessageStore([in] VARIANT newVal);
    [propget, id(5), helpstring("property Directory")] HRESULT Directory([out, retval] VARIANT *pVal);
    [propput, id(5), helpstring("property Directory")] HRESULT Directory([in] VARIANT newVal);
    [propget, id(6), helpstring("property MessageCount")] HRESULT MessageCount([out, retval] VARIANT *pVal);
};
```

Much thanks.

EDIT:

To make things clear, all of these `VARIANT`s could be replaced by explicit types.

Comment: looks like you inherited my project.  sorry :p  so VARIANTs are basically generic types that can be anything.  They're like Object in c#.  The idea is that these types can change at runtime.  This is so that your interface can be compatible with runtime type binding languages (like VB, C#, etc.).

Comment: Well, check the error handling in the code first.  Nice if it generates a friendly error message through IErrorInfo.  If you leave it up to the IDispatch stock implementation then the DISP_E_BADVARTYPE, "Bad variable type" you'd get when a variable of the wrong type is passed is not the greatest.  Get a better answer by describing the scripting language that's most commonly used with this server.

Comment: Only a C++ application uses this COM server.

Answer (score 1):

If you need performance or simplification, you change VARIANT type for appropriate values, more closely to type used. Remember, it is an interface break.
 
View valid values to use :
[COM Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sak564ww.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your interface derives from `IDispatch` which means it's a dual interface - you can call the methods directly from the interface, or you can call them through [`iDispatch::Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The parameters passed to `Invoke` must all be of type `VARIANTARG` which is just another name for `VARIANT`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891678.aspx.

Comment: So to have the capability of being a dual interface all of the parameters in the interface have to be of type `VARIANT`? `Invoke` doesn't handle the marshaling from `VARIANT` to the types described in the interface?

Comment: IDispatch::Invoke() is supposed to do all the marshaling.

Answer (score 0):

For certain types of dual interfaces that suppose to work with `VB` and scripting languages it is better to use `VARIANT` that direct type. For example it is better to use `VARIANT` over almost all kind of `SAFEARRAY` and interface pointers. But you may test and see.